# Imported currency symbol in Excel cell $ is not 'auto' converted when I format as currency

Tags: excel, currency

I import a bank statement that has $ symbol in cell contents. I was expecting Excel to accommodate this when I format the cell as Currency (Dollar) and remove the $ from the value but have as the format displayed.

However this does not seem to be the case. I have to manually remove the symbol and then format as currency. I need to do this in order for a simple column sum to work.

Any ideas on the right 'process' to use to convert csv data so I don't have to do a find/replace?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open CSV with column that has $ in each cell prefixing the value.
2. add column sum total to the bottom of the column
3. Convert column formatting to currency

- Expected: Sum of Dollars in column in Currency format.
- Actual: No value displayed in sum cell.

Excel 365 version 2101 on Windows 10

Thanks

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. How, exactly, are you importing the CSV?  When I import a CSV with `$` preceding a numeric string, the values get interpreted as currency type.  Are you sure you are **importing** and not just **opening** the csv file?

Comment: Sorry just opening.

Comment: In general, it is best to **import** csv files. Then you can inform Excel of the data type before it is processed (often incorrectly).  In O365, I suggest you start with `Data=>Get&Transform=>from Text/CSV`.  If any columns seem to have been interpreted incorrectly, you can select `Transform`. Otherwise, just accept the defaults. If the CSV file is updated, the query can also be updated. *The legacy wizard is also available, but is less flexible*

Comment: @RonRosenfeld   Seems to solve it...add as an answer and I will mark it as correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is best to import `csv` files. Then you can inform Excel of the data type before it is processed (often incorrectly).

In `O365`, I suggest you start with `Data=>Get&Transform=>from Text/CSV`. If any columns seem to have been interpreted incorrectly, you can select `Transform`. Otherwise, just accept the defaults.

If the CSV file is updated, the query can also be updated.

*The legacy wizard is also available, but is less flexible*